# How to keep a highly active mind satisfied?

Tags: learning, motivation, autism, aspergers

How can you keep a highly active mind satisfied?

Even more specifically:

- when one has tried many ways to learn but seemingly runs out of new things to learn about or do,
- at an older age,
- After graduating,
- for people potentially with autism/asperger's.

Comment: There is so much to learn, it is not imaginable to me that it is possible to run out; rather, there is an incredibly finite time we have. Perhaps you have not gone into much depth in the things you have studied? Are you fluent in every world language? A virtuoso with every instrument? Master of all cuisines?